# Background image extra space below the image

Tags: html, css

How can I remove below extra space? Below is my HTML mark that I am trying. There is a gap below the image, but it doesn't seems to be a padding/margin.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .backcss {
                background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/08/25/14/40/wall-175686_960_720.jpg");
                background-color: #cccccc;
                height: 100vh;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                display: block;
                padding: 0px !important;
                margin: 0px !important;
                background-position: center, center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="display: block;" class="backcss">
            <h1 style="color:white">Hello World!</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any space. Or are you referring to the default margin on body? have you tried `body { margin: 0; }`?

Comment: Margin is not coming from `<div class="backcss">`, it's the body.

Comment: I copied your code and I don't see any space below

Comment: i tried body css file still is not working

Comment: see image  it has extra space at bottom : https://www.dropbox.com/s/1f2ib04rnwjxith/erorr.png?dl=0

Comment: i am using google chrome. this extra space is not coming in mozila

Answer (score 1):

There is no padding below the image in the code you posted.
If you would like to remove the padding **above** it try

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

EDIT: Actually it's coming from the h1 tag so:

```
h1 {
margin:0;
}
```

Or better option:

```
.backss {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin comes from the body element, which most major browsers use as default. Simply remove the margin on the body element with:
    body { margin: 0; }.
You can further refer to https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ to see which elements browsers tend to differently, and which are the ones that are styled by your browser within their own user-agent-stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin and padding with the code here.

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Or

```
h1 {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```